# Facebook Tab iFrame blurring the Facebook Search Bar on Google Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, iframe, facebook-iframe

I am developing a Facebook iFrame application.  I am having display issues on Google Chrome.  When scrolling down past the iFrame, and then back up again, the search box from the Facebook header is getting trapped in the iFrame multiple times.  This does not happen on Firefox or Safari.

This screenshot illustrates the problem:

[image: Screenshot of the Facebook iFrame]

Has anyone encountered this before?  Any idea what is causing this and what might prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Does it do it to all page tab apps? Or just the one you're developing?  Does it happen on any computer other than yours?

I cannot repro it on any scrollable page tab apps using Chrome. I've tried a few.

So your issue might either be 1) with your browser, 2) with your side, 3) with your OS, 4) with your video card.

Answer (score 0):

WOW! Have you got this issue with another tabs as well? If not, then I'm quite sure your code is not valid HTML, and you can generate something for Chrome, what is "never happend, don't care" category. Make sure, your tab code is valid first.

Use this to validate: http://validator.w3.org/